# Is it possible to turn off ligatures when using semantics package

Tags: programming-tools

I'm using the semantics package to produce inference rules. My inference rules contains quite a lot of `\langle` and `\rangle`, so I've made ligatures for these commands as such:

```
\mathlig{<}{\langle}
\mathlig{>}{\rangle}
```

However, now I can't use `<` in equations to mean "less than", since it is turned into `\langle`.

Answer (score 1):

The [semantics package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/semantic/semantic.pdf) recommends the `\mathligsoff` command in this case, i.e.

```
\mathligsoff $1 < 10$ \mathligson
```